# How do I configure the locale and language of Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

How do I configure Azure Web Role to have United Kingdom (as opposed to US) as it's language/regional settings etc for all accounts? I believe I can RDP in and change it. However I want to set it to default on creation of the web role. It is making a difference to some classic ASP pages we have in a legacy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Can't say I've attempted this before. What you want is to set a different locale at startup so that it is always enforced as VMs making up your Web Role may be rebooted from time to time.

Unless someone comes up with a better idea you could try to modify the registry from a [Windows Azure Startup Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx). You would need to know which user locale to modify and you would need a registry changing CmdLet like this one (though I haven't tried it): [Set-RegistryKey](http://www.vexasoft.com/cmdletlibrary/support/setregistrykey.html).

Given you can figure out what registry value to modify and what user is running your IIS this could be done.

Use a Startup Task. Call a Cmd script and envoke a PowerShell script. Call the CmdLet and set the locale you want.

I realize this is not a complete solution, just a suggestion. Hopefully it is worth while.

Comment: Certainly worth a look. I guess it isn't a standard requirement